# How can I count # of occurences of more than one column (eg city & country)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following data ...

```
     city country
0  London      UK
1   Paris      FR
2   Paris      US
3  London      UK
```

... I'd like a count of each city-country pair

```
     city country  n
0  London      UK  2
1   Paris      FR  1
2   Paris      US  1
```

The following works but feels like a hack:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('London', 'UK'), ('Paris', 'FR'), ('Paris', 'US'), ('London', 'UK')], columns=['city', 'country'])

df.assign(**{'n': 1}).groupby(['city', 'country']).count().reset_index()
```

I'm assigning an additional column `n` of all 1s, grouping on city&country, and then `count()`ing occurrences of this new 'all 1s' column. It works, but adding a column just to count it feels wrong.

Is there a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better way..use `value_counts`

```
df.value_counts().reset_index(name='n')
```

---

```
     city country  n
0  London      UK  2
1   Paris      FR  1
2   Paris      US  1
```

Comment: Thank you! `value_counts()` is what I was looking for but could not find. Thanks also for the `(name='n')` in the call to `reset_index()` to name the count column -- I would not have known how to do that. Great answer!